# Bind Resource Dictionary to Combobox

Tags: c#, wpf

I need help with the binding of a resource dictionary collection to a Combo box.

Currently i managed to make this binding but i get displayed in combo box (Collection) and the logic behind works as it should.

The property that i bind is an Observable Collection of Resource Dictionaries.

I am aware that i need to create a converter for this but i`m not sure how ( I need the name of the dictionary displayed )

Any hints and help is greatly appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: Please paste some code you have tried!!

Comment: A simple example of converts is here http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html

Comment: I know how to create a converter, but i don't know how to take the name of the resource dictionary and to display it in the combo box instead of this (Collection).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set **[DisplayMemberPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)** property on ComboBox.

> Gets or sets a path to a value on the source object to serve as the
>   visual representation of the object.

Since you haven't posted any code, I assume you have `Name` property on collection or any other property which you want to show in comboBox. Use like this:

```
<ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
```